# Fix Windows Explorer quick access

Tags: windows-10

Environment: Windows 10 1903

I modify the drive letter of a partition like from E to D, then the Windows Explorer quick access links that point to folders under E is broken. Can I fix this manually? There seems to be no option for this in the property dialog of the quick access item. I don't want to delete/recreate the link since I want to preserve the position of the link in the quick access list. Note: I don't use the recent file feature, all the links in my quick access list was added manually by drag the folder to quick access area.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to change the target of anything pinned directly to Quick Access without removing and pinning again.

> "*Windows Explorer quick access links that point to folders under E is
>   broken. Can I fix this manually?*"
>
> "*I don't want to delete/recreate the link since I want to preserve
>   the position of the link in the quick access list.*"

The list is manually configurable.  Drag items to the position you prefer.

You may want to consider placing your shortcuts in a pinned folder, just like what you'd do for a toolbar.   You can easily modify the target location of each shortcut on the folder because they are not directly pinned to quick access.

Comment: I don't want to delete/create/drag manually. I'm asking a way to edit the link in place. There should be a system folder to store these links, but basic search didn't give a right result about this.

Comment: @jw_ There is a system folder but as I've already said, you cannot edit the target.  The answer to your question is to unpin/repin and manually move them.  If you want add new requirements then you should edit your question instead of putting them in the comments, if you just wanted to complain about software not doing want you want then you needn't have bothered posting a question in the first place, and if you want to argue about how to update your links then you need to explain how you will successfully edit the destinations-ms files or educate yourself with more than a basic search.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same issue after moving the destination folders from one drive to a newer drive with more room. I was unable to pin the folder from their new destination. It is an easy fix. Just delete the original pins and when you pin the newly located folders to quick access they will work.

As stated before all pins can be moved into any order within the pin list position.